# Nonparametric vs Parametric distributions

Tags: probability

I don't understand the difference between nonparametric and parametric probability distributions?
I have tried to google it, but it doen't give sense to me.
Can you help?

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics? Can you clarify what precisely you understand, and what still escapes you?

Answer (score 0):

In statistics the term nonparametric is most often used to describe inferential procedures. The Wikipedia article may be useful. However, because a lot of
the common statistical procedures assume that data are normal, colloquial
usage of 'nonparametric' sometimes just indicates that the normality assumption is not made.

Sign tests, rank-based tests (e.g., one and two-sample Wilcoxon, Kruskal-Wallis, and Friedman tests) and in many cases confidence intervals
associated with these tests are often found in the chapter of an elementary or intermediate-level statistics text called 'Nonparametric Tests'. While the rank-based tests do not assume sampling from a normal distribution, they do assume
continuous data (to the extent that there are few, if any, ties).

When data are reduced to ranks, information is lost. So it is not a good idea
to use rank-based nonparametric tests when data are normal or nearly normal.

Some permutation tests are also called nonparametric, and they do not necessarily require continuous data. Density estimation is largely nonparametric.

Please leave a comment if you want more detail on any of this, or if you need an explanation that goes in another direction entirely.